# What does the mirror do?

Tags: enter-the-gungeon

I found a mirror. I couldn't interact with it with <kbd>E</kbd>, so naturally I broke it. After that, a chest icon appeared on the map, but I still don't see anything in the room.

How does the mirror room work?

[image: Mirror and chest icon on map]

Comment: such new game :o

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Mirrors will show an unlocked [chest](http://enterthegungeon.gamepedia.com/Chests) in their reflection. The chest can be opened, which will shatter the mirror and increase the player's [curse](http://enterthegungeon.gamepedia.com/Curse). The mirror will also shatter if the player shoots it, which will increase the player's curse and make the chest inaccessible.

http://enterthegungeon.gamepedia.com/Mirror

Answer (score 1):

you can open the chest or break it, both options will curse you.

If you want to open the chest, you have to step away from it, and if you press "E" (or "A" on controller) when your reflection is facing the chest, an object or weapon will apear and the mirror will break.

I'm not sure what curse is for, but I think one of it's effects is that you have a higer chance to find stronger enemies.